# emacs constantly asking before saving python code with # -*- coding: ASCII -*-

Tags: python, emacs, character-encoding

I have  a python script that starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: ASCII -*-
```

and prior to saving, it always splits my window, and asks:

Warning (mule): Invalid coding system `ASCII' is specified
for the current buffer/file by the :coding tag.
It is highly recommended to fix it before writing to a file.

and I need to say yes, it there a way to disable this ? Sorry for asking but I had no luck on google.

Gabriel

Comment: From [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) "Without encoding comment, Python's parser will assume ASCII". So you don't need this at all in your file.

Comment: Also, from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2387315/623518) you can use `# coding: ascii` instead of the more verbose `# -*- coding: ASCII -*-`. This is also mentioned in PEP 263.

Comment: @Chris: why not put this in an answer?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the suggestion, I have done this.

Answer (score 7):

A solution that doesn't involve changing the script is to tell Emacs what `ASCII` means as a coding system.  (By default, Emacs calls it `US-ASCII` instead.)  Add this to your `.emacs` file:

```
(define-coding-system-alias 'ascii 'us-ascii)
```

Then Emacs should be able to understand `# -*- coding: ASCII -*-`.

Answer (score 3):

The Python Enhancement Proposal (PEP) 263, [Defining Python Source Code Encodings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), discusses a number of ways of defining the source code encoding. Two particular points are relevant here:

- > Without encoding comment, Python's parser will assume ASCII

  So you don't need this at all in your file. Still, if you do want to be explicit about the file encoding:
- > To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must be placed into the source files either as first or second line in the file, such as:

  ```
  # coding=<encoding name>
  ```

  (note that the `=` can be replaced by a `:`). So you can use `# coding: ascii` instead of the more verbose `# -*- coding: ASCII -*-`, as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2387315/623518) answer. This seems to keep emacs happy.

Comment: "Without encoding comment, Python's parser will assume ASCII"  -- if you're using python 2.x.  If you want ascii source and you're using python 3.x, then you do need it.